# Find impulse response and frequency response

Tags: frequency-response, impulse-response

Given
$$x(n)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u(n)-\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}u(n-1)$$ the input to a LTI system, and output
$$y(n)=\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n}u(n)$$
Find impulse and frequency responses.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SE.SP! This website isn't particularly keen on answering homework problem, unless  some clear effort has been made to solve them. Please *edit your question* with what you have tried, and where you are stuck

Comment: I have solved impulse response using Z-transform, and got the result as h(n)=-1.666(1/4)^n u(n)+2.666(1/5)^n u(n). But I am not able to find frequency response next. I am not remembering the steps next. Help.

Comment: The frequency response is the transfer function evaluated at $z = e^{j\omega}$: $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $h(n)$ = $H(z)$, so frequency response is $H(e^{j\omega})$.